# Fastest Way to Locate First Element In A Sequence of Recurring Elements

Tags: algorithm, scala

I wrote this binary search function to locate a particular value in an indexed sequence:

```
  def locate(xs: IndexedSeq[Int], x: Int, l: Int, h: Int): Int = {
    (l + h) / 2 match {
      case m if h - l <= 1 => l
      case m if x >= xs(m) => locate(xs, x, m, h)
      case m => locate(xs, x, l, m)
    }
  }
```

It works when I have a sequence such as:

```
Vector(1,2,3,9,15,26,89)
```

That is, an ordered sequence of unique elements. But it doesn't work when there are recurring elements in the ordered sequence such as:

```
Vector(1,2,3,3,15,15,89)
```

It is not guaranteed to select the first element of a recurring subsequence. For example, if I wanted to search for 3 it might not give me the index of the first 3 in the sequence.

Which algorithm can do this efficiently? Or can I modify my binary search sequence in a way to allow me to achieve this easily (whilst still being tail-recursive).

Comment: `indexOf(x)` gives the first index of x.

Comment: @Brian, `indexOf` is `O(n)` - bad.

Comment: Inspire yourself: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

Comment: @JuanLopes, cheers for that ; good performance profile for that algorithm as well.

Comment: Question 1: Do you really expect the caller to have to pass in the initial lowest and highest bounds themselves?  Your function can work that out itself from the size of the given sequence and then recur on an inner function (which only needs 2 arguments - l and h).

Comment: @itsbruce, it's a general function and so it can be used in various situations, one being that you may want to only search on a sub range of a large sequence.

Comment: Question 2: If the sequence doesn't contain the target value, your function returns the last item lower than it.  Is that the intent?  If your function returned Option[Int], you could return None for no match (which would enable it not to crash when passed an empty sequence, as a bonus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the algorithm for [C++'s lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/), I think this change would be enough:

```
def locate(xs: IndexedSeq[Int], x: Int, l: Int, h: Int): Int = {
    l+(h-l)/2 match {
        case m if h - l == 0 => l
        case m if xs(m) < x => locate(xs, x, m+1, h)
        case m => locate(xs, x, l, m)
    }
}
```

I also changed the code for computation of `m` as the original code was susceptible to integer overflow in extreme cases.

Comment: That's cool. I see how that works; if there is a recurring sequence the algorithm will narrow down on that subsequence and will keep repeating the last case statement until h-l == 0, after which `l` will be index of the first element.